# iphone application landsape mode issue

Tags: iphone

As my application working fine in Portrait mode but if i change it to landscape mode ,my design look weird,can any one help,is it any common mechanism to design for portrait as well as for landscape mode and which event get fire when we change actual device from portrait to landscape mode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to design for both orientations. You may like to consider having a portrait orientation nib and a landscape orientation nib if you are building your interface with interface builder. Otherwise you will need to cope with this in your programmatic view code.

Have a look at the AlternateViews sample code at developer.apple.com for a sample.